# Why does Xcode want me to add "#available" checks when the Deployment Target is already at a higher version?

Tags: ios, swift

My SwiftUI project has its Deployment Target version set to 15.0. However, when I try to use the new `Logger` API, I'm still getting warnings about the SDK is only available for iOS 14 or above.

Could it be that an extension to `UIImage` requires something special? I have a few other files that I used the Logger and the compiler isn't complaining.

[image: 'Logger' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer]
[image: 'appendInterpolation(_:format:align:privacy:)' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer]
[image: Target - Deployment Info]
[image: Project - Deployment Target]

Comment: Your app target may be configured for iOS 15 but the Widget that accompanies it, or the tests, may not be.

Comment: Hey matt, thanks for looking into this one. Unfortunately the Widget is also configured as iOS 15. My spider sense suggests that it must have something to do with UIImage. There is no problems as long as I am not trying to provide an extension to a system class like UIImage.

Comment: Unfortunately, then, it seems you haven't given enough information to reproduce the issue. Try it in a totally new freshly made project created with Xcode 13: just make a UIImage extension with a function in it that refers to Logger. You will see that there is no such issue as you describe.

Comment: Are you using Pods? if yes, make sure you updated Podfile. You can also run `grep IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET -R ./*` from the root directory of your project, and see that _all_ returned values are consistently 15.

Comment: Kiril, thank you. That was an excellent tip. (BTW, I'm using the Package Manager but the advice is still the right direction.)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Kiril, the problem happens because the Test Project was targeting 13.2.

Grep showed that `project.pbxproj` file has a `13.2` specified. After changing the xml file directly, the problem disappeared.

(I didn't notice this because the test Target doesn't have a place showing the "Deployment Info".